# Wireshark filter syntax needed

Tags: syntax, wireshark, diameter-protocol

I would like to filter requests in Wireshark.

I have Diameter request which is for example SLR and has concrete session ID and is sent to specified IP destination address. Like SLR - send to 10.44.190.40

I would like to filter every request where session started to this node, but STR with the same session ID went to other destination address.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Im not familiar with SLR/STR but basically in wireshark you can show each protocol specific field in a column. try first to output the field as column, and if its possible - probably filtering by that field is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to filter on diameter.Session-Id?
Go to Packet details
Expand Diameter Protocol
Right-click on Session-ID (for example: diameter.Session-Id == "supauth.eap.testbed.aaa;1273828925;1;client;gw.eap.testbed.aaa")
Select Apply as Filter
Go to Statistics -> Conversations
Select IPv4
Check "Limit to display filter"

Links [Statistics menu](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUseStatisticsMenuSection.html), [Wireshark Display Filter Reference](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/d/diameter.html) and [Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DIAMETER)

Hope this helps.